# Interpreting VECM impulse response function

Tags: econometrics, stata, vector-error-correction-model, impulse-response

I have plotted IRF in stata with response S&P500 and impulse treasury bill rate. According to the model they are positively related. However, my irf graph is below zero(see the graph below). How do I interpret such a result?[image: impulse(LTBR) response(LSP)]

Comment: Is the actual problem in reading the graph or in reconciling what you think is implied by the model with what you see in the graph?

Comment: The problem is with reading the graph

Comment: Well, the graph shows impulse responses (literally). What is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Shock to t-bills results in a negative response in S&P500. It could be that higher t-bill rates depress S&P500. Your VAR may not be dynamically stable as the IRF does not die out.